# CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource for Spring boot application with authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am working on a Spring Boot application. I have setup a login API (`/api/v1/auth`) that can be accessed without authentication and the rest of the APIs (e.g. `/api/v1/test`) need authentication.

The auth api works without any errors, but when I call the test API, I get the following error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I believe something is missing in my `getSecurityFilterChain`. Can someone please help me figure it out?

My security configuration class looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain getSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/v1/auth/**"))
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                        .allowCredentials(false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I went through several questions on StackOverflow and some blogs and most of them recommend addition of `addCorsMappings` which I already have in my code. Note that I don't get CORS error for the API that doesn't need authentication (`/api/v1/auth`). I get CORS errors for all the APIs that need authentication.

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurer`is used for spring `MVC` applications, is this an mvc application?

Comment: It is a Spring Boot application. I have added the `WebMvcConfigurer` bean in my configuration class.

Comment: i would suggest that you read the actual spring documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html is the docs for the class you are using it states it is used with the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. And there is an entire chapter in the spring security docs about CCORS https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html#page-title

Comment: @Rohan *I get CORS errors for all the APIs that need authentication* Then, why you are disallowing credentials with `.allowCredentials(false)`? Further more, if you want to configure CORS, you should do it in your Spring Security configuration not only in your Spring Web configuration.

Comment: BTW: You can't use wildcard origin in authenticated request. CORS doesn't allow it. You have to name a domain, not a wildcard.